# find + delete files bigger than 2G and when there's less than X available space

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, find

How can I delete files called `stdout` / `stderr` that are located under the `/data/sdf` mount point, according to the following rules?

1. The available disk space (on `/dev/sdf`) is less than 100G
2. The `stdout` or `stderr` files are greater than 2G in size

   ```
   /data/sdf/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1575355124522_0458/container_e245_1575355124522_0458_01_000002/stdout
   /data/sdf/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1575355124522_0458/container_e245_1575355124522_0458_03_000002/stdout
   /data/sdf/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1515153382036_0001/container_e13_1515153382036_0001_02_000003/stdout
   ```

From `df -h`

```
/dev/sdf                   80G   76G  3.7G  82% /data/sdb
```

I have come up with the following `find` call to delete files based on their size,

```
find /grid/sdf -type f \( -name "stdout" -o -name "stderr" \) -size +2000M -delete
```

but do not know how to also check the free disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming GNU `df`, you can add a condition on the available disk space using for example

```
[[ $(df --output=avail -B1 /grid/sdf | tail -n 1) -lt 100*1024*1024*1024 ]] && \
find /grid/sdf -type f \( -name "stdout" -o -name "stderr" \) -size +2000M -delete
```

You can adapt this as necessary, for example to delete files as long as the available space is less than 100 GiB:

```
while [[ $(df --output=avail -B1 /grid/sdf | tail -n 1) -lt 100*1024*1024*1024 ]]; do
    find /grid/sdf -type f \( -name "stdout" -o -name "stderr" \) -size +2000M -delete -quit
done
```

(Note that this will loop endlessly if deleting these files doesn’t free up enough space.)

Instead of `df`, you can also use `findmnt`: replace `df --output=avail -B1 /grid/sdf | tail -n 1` with `findmnt -nbo AVAIL /grid/sdf` (no need for `tail`).